# Using Anchor Links aka Jump To Links with Internal Linking Strategy

Tags: seo, links, anchor

Do anchor links that link to another page help or hurt SEO internal linking strategy?

For example, let's say I have two pages:

- `example.com/services`
- and `example.com/services/subtopic-service`.

And, on `/subtopic-service` I have anchor links like:

```
example.com/services/subtopic-service#section
```

And, I link to that anchor like from the higher level page `/services`.

I know that anchor links aren't indexed. But, will I get the same SEO benefit from an internal link with an anchor link?